# How do I get Jetty to reload the .class files for each new build from Eclipse when running an AppEngine Servlet locally?

Tags: google-app-engine, jetty

I've successfully created a "Hello world" AppEngine project in Eclipse Juno. The problem is that I have to restart Eclipse each time I do a code change in order to get Jetty to provide me with the result from the latest code. Even stopping and restarting Jetty from Eclipse using the Terminate-button from the Console tab does not help. I can see that Jetty is reloading *something* because the log produces this line, among many others:

```
INFO: Successfully processed C:\coding\source\projects\HelloWorld\Service\war\WEB-INF/web.xml
```

I have also checked that the timestasmp of the .class-file in the output folder `war/WEB-INF/
classes/...` is updated. It is not a browser caching issue either, since I've tried it in two separate browsers.

Anyone?

Comment: I have seen this problem occur on a regular basis. The only sure way that I have been able to address this is to a) To a Project Clean in Eclipse b) Restart the Local Dev Server

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was running multiple Jetty services at once. I now realize I have to terminate each one of them before launching a new one.

[image: List of running and terminated jetty sessions]

If anyone know if it's possible to make Eclipse automatically shut down each server before launching a new one, I'd be happy to learn.